# How to show all photos folder when user select gallery option

Tags: android, android-camera

How to show all photos folder when user select gallery option in android

Comment: Where is that gallery option in Android?

Comment: For select image we will use camera Intent there

Answer (score 0):

Here whole code for custom dialog box and to select image .

```
btnSelect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnselect);

btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //custom dialogBox
            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
            dialog.setTitle("Select from..");

            //set the custom dialog components
            TextView txtmsg=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
          Button btnGallaery=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btngallery);
            Button btnCamara=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncamara);

            btnGallaery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent image=new Intent();
                    image.setType("image/*");
                    image.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(image,"select file"),SELECT_IMAGE);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });




            btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent cam=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                    cam.putExtra("Image", fileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(cam,REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    dialog.dismiss();



                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
         return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
    * returning image / video
    */
   private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {

         mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");

    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;

}
```

custom_dialog_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="From where to select Image ? "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/txtmsg"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btngallery"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btncamara"
        android:text="camara"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

     </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: look ,  default gallery is a third party App. so in that App sort option is given in different divice differently.

Comment: so if all photos displayed  by sorting option which will be based on albums or recent or date wise may be. so in third party App we can not make changes. it differs based on the model.